# How can I put content div inside a table

Tags: html, css

Currently I find myself a table that contains within it a div with a video player, but is moved around on the left side of the screen, I'd like to hit GrindPlayer, how can I do?

```
   <style type="text/css" media="screen">
         #GrindPlayer p{
         text-align:center;
         }
         #GrindPlayer{
         margin:0 auto;
         }
         </style>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="GrindPlayer">
                        <p>
                            Alternative content
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and if I can put the full table at the top of the screen. Thank you

Comment: not sure if that's an issue with pasting, but your `table` isn't properly closed ;)

Comment: where do you want your div to end up?
At the moment it's inside a single cell within a table. I would expect it to be on the left.

Comment: It is now left of the screen, but I wish it were in the center of the screen

Answer (score 1):

If you want the div inside the table at the center, this is the solution.

```css
#GrindPlayer p{
  text-align:center;
}
#GrindPlayer{
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="GrindPlayer">
                        <p>
                            Alternative content
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: I made the change to the file as the first post, but evidently something wrong

Comment: I created a CSS file, but the player I remains left of the screen

Comment: @Miko did you include the CSS file in your HTML file?

Comment: I have tried both to include it in the html between the head tags that creating a stile.css file recall by inserting between the head tags with `<link href = "stile.css" rel = "stylesheet" type = "text / css">` but not change anything in neither case

Comment: make sure that your html and css files are in the same folder.         <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="5">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="GrindPlayer">
                        <p>
                            Alternative content
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
  </table>
  </html>

Comment: The html file and css files in the same folder